# vertx how to reroute with query params

Tags: vert.x

Due to some url versioning, we try to map multiple paths to the same handler.

I tried to achieve this via rerouting but the query parameters get lost in the process.

```
// reroute if the path contains apiv3 / api v3
        router.route("/apiv3/*").handler( context -> {
            String path = context.request().path();
            path = path.replace("apiv3/", "");
            LOG.info("Path changed to {}", path);
            context.reroute(path);
        });
```

What is the most elegant way around this problem?

There are some discussions on google groups but surprisingly nothing quick and simple to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reroute](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_reroute) documentation says:

> It should be clear that reroute works on paths, so if you need to
>   preserve and or add state across reroutes, one should use the
>   RoutingContext object.

So you could create a global catch-all route that stores any query param in the `RoutingContext`:

```
router.route().handler(ctx -> {
        ctx.put("queryParams", ctx.queryParams());
        ctx.next();
    });
```

Then your `apiv3` catch-all route:

```
router.route("/apiv3/*").handler( context -> {
  String path = context.request().path();
  path = path.replace("apiv3/", "");
  LOG.info("Path changed to {}", path);
  context.reroute(path);
});
```

Finally an actual route handler:

```
router.get("/products").handler(rc -> {
  MultiMap queryParams = rc.get("queryParams");
  // handle request
});
```

Comment: still it s hard to make sure that the future programmers do not forget this behavior and call the usual : ctx.params().get("...")  .

Comment: we could inherit from RoutingContext and change the behavior of getting params, but there can be side effects to this as well..

Comment: Yes. I answered your question about `reroute` usage but if it's not a hard technical requirement, I would rather explore mounting the API routes to both the top level router and a sub router on `/apiv3`